# why do I get a glow effect in my render with bloom turned off?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

i'm trying to render a scene but I'm getting a glow effect in my render no matter which settings I choose. Especially around the spaceship on the monitor the glow is clearly visible. I turned off everything in the render tab but nothing helps.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any additional effects added in the compositor?

Comment: no ther is no effect in the compositor

Comment: Isn't the glow baked into the image you're using ?

Comment: the picture was made in after effects, there I chose a glow effect for the sun but not for the rest. When I render in Blender it shows the result i'd like to get in the renderscreen for about 2 secs before applying the effect.